# 400 - Bad Request on Apache POST sending JSON

Tags: java, apache, rest, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to make a REST call from my class using the Apache. But its giving the 400 exception when I print the response of the REST service. Kindly find the code below and let me know the changes that needs to be made to make it working,

```
    List<NameValuePair> pickup = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    ArrayList<HashMap> pickupItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    String [] productIds = prop.getArray("vproductIDs");
    String [] quantities = prop.getArray("vquantities");
    String [] tprices = prop.getArray("vtprices");
    String [] bprices = prop.getArray("vbprices");

    HashMap pickupObjMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    pickupObjMap.put("loyaltyId",prop.getString("loyaltyId"));
    pickupObjMap.put("loyaltyFName",prop.getString("loyaltyFName"));
    pickupObjMap.put("orderId",prop.getString("orderId"));
    pickupObjMap.put("locationId",prop.getString("locationId"));
    pickupObjMap.put("consignmentId",prop.getString("consignmentId"));
    pickupObjMap.put("description",prop.getString("description"));
    pickupObjMap.put("retailerId",prop.getString("retailerId"));
    pickupObjMap.put("pickupType",Integer.parseInt(prop.getString("pickupType")));
    pickupObjMap.put("email",prop.getString("email"));
    pickupObjMap.put("loyaltyLName",prop.getString("loyaltyLName"));
    pickupObjMap.put("status",prop.getString("status"));

    for(int i=0; i<productIds.length ; i++){
        HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("sku", productIds[i]);
        map.put("quantity", Double.parseDouble(quantities[i]));
        map.put("totalPrice", Double.parseDouble(tprices[i]));
        map.put("basePrice", Double.parseDouble(bprices[i]));
        pickupItemList.add(map);
    }
    pickup.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pickupItemList", pickupItemList.toString()));
    pickup.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pickupObj", pickupObjMap.toString()));
    pickup.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ovclid", prop.getString("ovclid")));

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Target URL");
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pickup));
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                int cp;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) cp);
                }
                System.out.println("String Response......."+sb);
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Response......."+entity.getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Below is the response that I get upon making the REST Call.

```
Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') 
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@175d5e8a; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected character "P" as in "POST", looks like the server returns html instead of json. Can you check server logs and see any exception? What is the return type - it should be json

```
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

If you are using glassfish you may have stumbled upon this bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231159

Comment: There are no exceptions found in the server. Also i tried to make the call using postman it worked find and i'm getting the valid response from the server as well.

Comment: Can you share your curl command or whatever way you are calling it? Suggest to try with curl first.

Comment: Hi Sheetal,
I just tested it using the Postman. Kindly find the details below,

URL : http://ibmwcs.ovcdemo.com:8080/json/process/execute/CreatePickup

Header :
Content-Type application/json

Body:
{
   "param1":"test@test.com"
}

Comment: Can u share you rest call code that gives you error?

Comment: There are no exceptions when I make a call from Postman. But when i make the same using the mentioned code im getting the 400(Bad Request) as the response status code. Along with that it gives the response message body as,

Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') 

where it reads the 'p' of the json object "pickupItemList" itstead of reading it as a whole letter.